# removing comma at the end of each line only

Tags: html, regex

I have a list that contains a comma but I also have others commas in the same list I dont want to remove, so I wonder is there a way to only delete the last comma of every line of text?

Comment: Sure there is. Using which language or tool? Would you care to show us some input? And what have you tried?

Comment: Please clarify - did you mean if the last character of the line is a comma, remove it, or do you mean remove the last comma wherever it is, as long as its the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean remove the last character if it is a comma, then you should do something like
replace 
`^(.*),$` with `$1`

`a,b,c,` will be replaced to `a,b,c`, and `a,b,c,d` will not match the regex.

If you means just remove the last comma, even there are something after it, do something like replace `^(.*),([^,]*)$` with `$1$2`

`a,b,c,` will be replaced to `a,b,c`, and `a,b,c,d` will be replaced to `a,b,cd`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is with a regex statement like:

replace( /,\s*$/, '', [content] );

This will look for a comma character (,) followed by any whitespace (\s*) at the end of the line ($). Depending on the language or program, you'll have to pass each line in individually, or set a multi-line flag.

Comment: The OP said the last comma, not necessarily the comma at the end of the line.

Comment: I'd rather use `[^,]*` instead of `\s*` because the latter is rather restrictive. but we can't really know without more input from the OP

Answer (score 1):

Because we don't know what language you're using, I can only give you the regex that will capture the *last* comma:

```
,(?!.*,)
```

If you replace matches of this regex with a blank, you'll remove the last comma.

Thus regex uses a lookahead to assert that there are no commas anywhere after the matched comma. The good thing about look arounds is the are non capturing, so you don't have to replace with any back references etc.

Answer (score 1):

RegEx is nice, but difficult to read.  If you would prefer a more verbose algorithm in a language like C#...

```
public string RemoveLastComma(string input)
{
if (input.Contains(",") == false)
    return input;

    int position = 0;

    for (int i = input.Length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (input.Substring(i-1, 1) == ",")
        {
            position = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    var firstSegment = input.Substring(0, position-1);
    var lastSegement = input.Substring(position, (input.Length - position));
    return firstSegment + lastSegement;
}
```